# Javascript... Why will this not go into the else section of the if statement?

Tags: javascript, html

See here on codepen...
[https://codepen.io/johnstonf/pen/qBbbpaV?editors=1011]

Javascript... Why will this not go into the else section of the if statement when the condition variable shows it should.  It works the first time (click the button), but the second time, it should reverse function, to clear the clipboard, but it does the if section again.

```
<div id="fj33">
    <h5>Sensitive Data For Clipboard</h5>
    <p>Sensitive Data Line 2</p>
</div>
<div id="fj34">
    <h5>Clipboard Cleared</h5>
    <p>Sensitive Data Gone</p>
</div>

<button id="fjCopyTxtButton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copyText()">Copy Text to Clipboard!!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function copyText() {
    fjChk=fjCopyTxtButton.innerHTML.includes("COPIED");
    console.log("CURRENT-(Before-IF):",fjChk);
    if(fjChk != "true")
    {
      console.log("CURRENT1:",fjChk);
      //console.log("...now false");
      var range, selection, worked, fj, fj2;
      fj=document.querySelector('#fj33');
      fj2=fj.innerText
      console.log(fj2);
      var copyhelper = document.createElement("textarea");
      copyhelper.className = 'copyhelper'
      document.body.appendChild(copyhelper);
      copyhelper.value = fj2;
      fj3=copyhelper.value;
      copyhelper.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      document.body.removeChild(copyhelper);
      document.querySelector('#fjCopyTxtButton').style.backgroundColor='yellow';
      document.querySelector('#fjCopyTxtButton').style.color='red';
      document.querySelector('#fjCopyTxtButton').innerHTML = '<h3>Text COPIED</h3>';
    } else {
      console.log("CURRENT2:",fjChk);
      console.log("...now true in else section");   
      fj=document.querySelector('#fj34');
      fj2=fj.innerText
      console.log(fj2);
      var copyhelper = document.createElement("textarea");
      copyhelper.className = 'copyhelper'
      document.body.appendChild(copyhelper);
      copyhelper.value = fj2;
      fj3=copyhelper.value;
      copyhelper.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      document.body.removeChild(copyhelper);
      document.querySelector('#fjCopyTxtButton').style.backgroundColor='green';
      document.querySelector('#fjCopyTxtButton').style.color='black';
      document.querySelector('#fjCopyTxtButton').innerHTML = '<h3>Text CLEARED</h3>';
  }};


 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (fjChk != "true")
```

You're checking for the string `"true"`, but fjChk is not a string. You need to check for a boolean.

```
if (fjChk !== true)
```

or

```
if (!fjChk)
```

Comment: Tested and verified... tx!